# JS - keydown execute multiple times when is inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <div class="comentPub" id="comentPub_<?php echo $pub_id;?>">

<div id="comentPub_content">

<img onclick="close_coment_box(<?php echo $pub_id; ?>)" src="imagens/x.png" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; float: right; margin-right: 10px;"/><br/>

<a href="perfil.php">
<img src="<?php echo $imageDirectory;?>" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;"> 
</a>

<textarea name="usercoment" class="comentBox" id="comentBox_<?php echo $pub_id;?>" placeholder="Escreve um coment&aacute;rio..." onkeypress="keypressed(this.id, <?php echo $userID;?>, <?php echo $pub_id;?>)"></textarea><br/
```

//THIS IS THE TEXTAREA THAT I WANT TO GET THE VALUE AND VERIFY THE KEYPRESSED FUNCTION

```
<li style="background: #ddd; font-size: 0; height: 1px; line-height: 0; width: 350px; float: left;"></li>

<?php
$comentarios = "SELECT * FROM comentPub WHERE pubID = '$pub_id'";
$comentarios_query = mysql_query($comentarios, $liga);

while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($comentarios_query)){

$userComentID = $row4['userID'];
$coment = $row4['coment'];
$comentID = $row4['comentID'];

$getUserComentData = "SELECT * FROM perfis WHERE id='$userComentID'";
                                    $getUserComentData_query = mysql_query($getUserComentData, $liga);

while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($getUserComentData_query)){

                                        $userComentImage = $row5['imagem'];
$nome = $row5['nome'].' '.$row5['apelidos'];

}
}
?>

</div>

</div>
```

^
THIS IS MY HTML PAGE, NOW MY JS FUNCTION

```
function keypressed(textareaID, comentUserID, pubID){

    var textareaID = "#" + textareaID;

    $(textareaID).keydown(function(e){ 

       if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 13){ 

        var txt = $(textareaID);
            txt.val(txt.val());

       } else if (e.keyCode == 13) { 

          e.preventDefault();

          var userComent = $(textareaID).val(); 

          $.post("comentar_pub.php", {coment: userComent, user: comentUserID, pub: pubID});      
          $(textareaID).attr("value", "");
       }
    });
}
```

NOW, IF YOU EXECUTE THAT, IT WILL EXECUTE MULTIPLE TIMES THE "$.post("comentar_pub.php", {coment: userComent, user: comentUserID, pub: pubID});" AND INSERT MULTIPLE LINES ON THE DB. IF YOU TRY TO CHANGE THE CODE INSIDE "e.keyCode == 13" TO "alert("1"); alert("2");", YOU CAN SEE BETTER THE EFFECT. PLEASE HELP

Comment: your formatting looks like a post-war bombed city scenario

Comment: Hey you tried `.keypress()` instead of `.keydown()`?

Comment: Take a look at `Jquery`, and how it can help with `unobtrusive javascript`

Comment: thank you all.  The Illimar Pihlamäe's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its one hell of a code to trace... Anyway, your problem seams to be that you fire the code on `onkeypress` in the `textarea` + in the function `keypressed()` you add another event listener `$(textareaID).keydown()` to the same element... you can see where this is going.

The thing to note here is that the jquery `keydown` adds in event listeners and does not replace the existing keydown. So every time the `onkeypress` is fired you add another `$(textareaID).keydown()` event action (the anonymous function that you pass to the event) to the `$(textareaID)` element.

On every keypress you add an event listener, when the keydown fires, the post is executed by the X amount of times the `onkeypress` has been fired on the `textarea`.

Remove the `$(textareaID).keydown()` event adding and run the code inside it instead and you should be set... if I understood correctly how this should work.

EDIT: So the code should be

```
<textarea name="usercoment" class="comentBox" id="comentBox_<?php echo $pub_id;?>" placeholder="Escreve um coment&aacute;rio..." onkeypress="keypressed(event, this, <?php echo $userID;?>, <?php echo $pub_id;?>)"></textarea>
```

and JS

```
function keypressed(e, textareaDOM, comentUserID, pubID){

    if (!e) var e = window.event;

    var txt = $(textareaDOM);

    if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 13){ 

        txt.val(txt.val());

    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) { 

        e.preventDefault();

        var userComent = txt.val(); 

        $.post("comentar_pub.php", {coment: userComent, user: comentUserID, pub: pubID});      
        txt.attr("value", "");
    }
}
```

NOTE! - Because the `keypressed` function is fires through the normal events and not jQuery events, then I do not remember if `e.shiftKey` actually works, if I remember correctly you still need to listen for shift separately. But I'll leave that up to you!

Comment: so you're saying that the js function should be:

function keypressed(textareaID, comentUserID, pubID){

    var textareaID = "#" + textareaID;

       if(textareaID.shiftKey && textareaID.keyCode == 13){ 

        var txt = $(textareaID);
            txt.val(txt.val());

       } else if (textareaID.keyCode == 13) { 

          textareaID.preventDefault();

          var userComent = $(textareaID).val(); 

          $.post("comentar_pub.php", {coment: userComent, user: comentUserID, pub: pubID});      
          $(textareaID).attr("value", "");
       }
}

Comment: @user3042700 this is blind code because this is impossible to check for me... well do not care to make a test senario. But it's something in th lines of that edit.

Comment: @user3042700 on a different note I see in your SQL that you are leaving your code open to data injecting (or maybe it simply seams like that from the snippet of code I can see.)

Comment: @user3042700 you know you'd be better of adding a jquery event listener on the textarea with something like `<script type="text/javascript">$('#comentBox_<?php echo $pub_id;?>').keypress(function(e){ keypressed(e, this.id, <?php echo $userID;?>, <?php echo $pub_id;?>); })</script>` and then you can more or less use your original code. Of cource you'd need to remove the `onkeypress` event from the textarea.

Comment: @user3042700 did you get this to work or should I try to make a fully functional test case for you? PS I am sorry if I was a bit rude to you earlier, I just got word that I have a 1w deadline on a 2w job and I think I took it out on you.

Comment: Illimar Pihlamae don't worry ;D Yes this worked and it's working. Thank you. I didn't thought that could be the function call, that was repeating the result... now I'am understanding about this ! You can see on tgdsrv.dyndns.org/its. This code is for comment the publishes.